# Two person sleeping bag liner for sleeping bag/staying in a hut?

Tags: sleeping-bags, sleeping

I am in eager search for any suggestions in terms of a personal sleeping bag liner we use for winter in our zipped together sleeping bags and for our summer tour we’re we mostly stay in huts. We cannot really use single sleeping bag liners, due to some condition. So we either need sleeping bag liners that are for 2 people. Or we use zip-together liners.

However it doesn’t seem to have such a thing on the market. All I find is half a blanked half an liners. But I need an liner for 2 people :/

Comment: It would be quite easy to make one, especially for hut use where polycotton would be fine (even then you might want to order the fabric as you may prefer a thinner material than bedsheets).

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean sleeping bag liners? If so, I've never seen a 2-person liner although they seem to exist. Consider buying two and going to a tailor/seamstress to get it modified. It shouldn't be expensive at all. I get lots of gear modified/fixed and after finding the right person, it costs me peanuts.

Comment: We have a 2 person liner for our sleeping bags but they're designed to work with brands which have joinable sleeping bags.

Comment: The same brand as the sleeping bag or aftermarket?

Comment: Either, not all UK brands do a liner for their bags so usually you buy one specifically.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I mean liner! This is great! Thank you

Comment: Who makes liners for zip-together bags? I'm having a tough time finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

If it is more about hygiene/comfort when sleeping in huts and not about warmth, you could just go with a **duvet/blanket cover**. After all they are essentially shaped like very big bag - and coming in all sizes you should easily find one that is big enough to be used by 2 people.